# Mupx setup hangs on Installing Docker

Tags: windows, meteor, meteor-up

The installer hangs when I use mupx setup on the first thing in the TaskList, Installing Docker.  I can't get the DEBUG=* mupx setup to work because DEBUG is not recognized as an internal or external command.

Server is through Linode, and the OS is Ubuntu 16.04.  I'm running Windows 8.1.  My project works fine on my end but I can't figure out mupx enough to get it over.  Docker is working fine on my computer as well as on my server from what I can tell.

How can I get the DEBUG to work (either a setting or a download)?  Or is this a common issue someone can walk me through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you run "mupx setup" first? That will install Docker and setup a new container on the remote server you entered into your local mup.json file

Comment: I apparently wasn't giving setup enough time.  Just let it crank through for an hour and it said completed with errors.  Errors turned out to be packages I wasn't using.  Annoying but it worked.